# Mouse stutters and jerks since upgrade to 21.10

Tags: mouse, 21.10, mouse-pointer

Since upgrading to 21.10, my wired mouse is stuttering and jerking.  There was no problem in earlier Ubuntu version.

Comment: Does it happen when using a live CD (boot to a Ubuntu install USB, and press Try Ubuntu **not** install Ubuntu, and then reboot and unplug that USB to get back to your normal OS)?

Comment: Mouse is fine otherwise